# able to keep current uploaded file name on image

Tags: php, html

I have been trying for like 2 days now and its been frustrating! so hopefully i will learn something new today :)

Right, i have a php page where i can upload up to 3 images, the code is in a table (shrinked down to show only image inputs)

```
<tr>
        <td align="right">1st Image</td>
        <td><label>
          <input type="file" name="fileField1" id="fileField1"/>
        </label></td>
      </tr>     

      <tr>
        <td align="right">2nd Image</td>
        <td><label>
          <input type="file" name="fileField2" id="fileField2" />
        </label></td>
      </tr> 
      <tr>
        <td align="right">3rd Image</td>
        <td><label>
          <input type="file" name="fileField3" id="fileField3" />
        </label></td>
```

the feilds are then stored in a upload slot via php -

```
if (isset($_FILES['fileField1'])) {
    $errors = array();
    $allowed_ext = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif');
    $file_name = $_FILES['fileField1']['name'];
    $global_file_name1 .= $file_name;
    $file_ext = strtolower(end(explode('.', $file_name)));
    $file_size = $_FILES['fileField1']['size'];
    $file_tmp = $_FILES['fileField1']['tmp_name'];

    if (in_array($file_ext, $allowed_ext) === false) {
        $errors[] = 'Extention not alowed';

    }

    if ($file_size > 2097152) {
        $errors[] = 'File must be under 2MB';
    }

    if (empty($errors)) {
        move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, 'upload/'.$file_name);
    } else {
        foreach ($errors as $error) {
            echo $error, '<br />';
            }
    }
```

*Code is same for all 3*

My problem is on the edit pages where you can change the other feilds (like name, details etc) when you then press submit the name is then changed to nothing as after a submit it submits what it has got which is nothing as the image hasnt been changed and was left.

My question is can i find a way of stopping the image if statement from going if nothing has been selected?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you re format the last paragraph? I can't quite make sense of it.

Comment: You've shown us an edited upload form and a snippet of PHP code, but not the edit page where you say the error is occurring. What do you want us to do?

Comment: Mike this is code from the edit page, Rottingham i will just re edit in a min sorry

Comment: Please show us the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the file size:

```
if ($_FILES['fileField1']['size']>0) {
    // new file has been submitted. Process it.
} else {
    // an empty field has been submitted. Do nothing.
}
```

Comment: Why even do that? if (count($_FILES) > 0) { proceed. }

Comment: But there are 3 files. First can be uploaded while 2 others will be empty. Need to check every entry.